# Decoding legacy binary format

Tags: string, unicode, internationalization, decode

I am trying to figure out how to decode a "legacy" binary file that is coming from a Windows application (anno ±1990). Specifically I have a trouble to understand what specific encoding is used for the strings that are being stored.

Example: a unicode string "Düsseldorf" is represented as "Du\06sseldorf" or hex "44 75 06 73 73 65 6C 64 6F 72 66" where everything is single-byte except "u + \06" that mysteriously become an u-umlaut.

Is it completely proprietary? Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this app pre-dates DBCS and Unicode, I suspect that it is proprietary.  It looks like they might be using the non-ASCII values below 31 to represent the various accent marks.

`\06` may indicate "put an umlaut on the previous character".

Try replacing the string with `"Du\05sseldorf"` and see if the accent changes over the u.  Then try other escaped values between 1 and 31, and I suspect you may be able to come up with a map for these escape characters.  Of course, once you have the map, you could easily create a routine to replace all of the strings with proper modern Unicode strings with the accents in place.

Comment: Thanks! I will go with the mapping table.